# htaccess redirect TLD preserve subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect some TLDs to a specific TLD, and I also want to preserve subdomains.

The followings are some redirect examples I need:

```
sub1.domain.net -> sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.net -> sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.net -> sub3.domain.com

sub1.domain.org -> sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.org -> sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.org -> sub3.domain.com
```

I have tried this code in my .htacess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-zA-Z_\-\.(0-9)]*)domain\.com
RewriteRule  ^ http://$1domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but $1 is not recognized as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1 is undefined in your example as you are not capturing the uri. To use the captured part of the hostaname ,you need %n variable.  :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\..+$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```